# pygame.rect is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

help me please i have this code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 800, 600
speed = [2, 2]
black = 1, 1, 1

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
player1 = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
player1rect = player1.get_rect()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    player1rect = player1rect.move(speed)
    if player1rect.w < 0 or player1rect.s > heght:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect) (player1, player1rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

and when i trying launch it it just saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Pong\pong.py", line 31, in <module>
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect) (player1, player1rect)
TypeError: 'pygame.Rect' object is not callable
```

so is there anybody who can help me? and i have trying almost everything and it will not work and if there is something more wrong with my code so please write it.

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace line 31 with two lines that say:

```
screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
screen.blit(player1, player1rect)
```

This should fix your problem